# How to record whatever is playing using AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to play a HTTP radio stream. Most of the code is following [StitchedStreamPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html).

Playing the audio stream is fine.

How do I also record the audio stream to file?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903542/using-avcapturesession-and-avaudioplayer-together

Comment: My scenario is different, and using different classes. AVPlayer is playing a the audio stream, and I want to record that audio stream.

Comment: Sorry man I have no idea.

Comment: @samwize did you every figure this out for avplayer I too am trying to record the audio stream as it plays?

Comment: I didn't have an answer..

Comment: hi...samwize.. i am also looking for same but for video recording. i want to record live rtsp/hls stream into mp4.. if you find any way to do  this... Would you please share with me ? .. your help really appriciated...